# JFormattedTextField and JComboBox

Tags: java, jcombobox, jformattedtextfield

How can I use `JFormattedTextField` with an editable `JComboBox`?

I know it is using internally an `JTextField`, but I only want it to accept numeric values with one decimal.

For this reason I want to use `JFormattedTextField`, but I´m not able to find the function in `JComboBox` to establish it.

Comment: i doubt you can replace the textfields. what you probably can do is to add a `DocumentListener` to the textfield used by the combobox. this would allow you to filter the text as well

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will point you in the right direction:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification